# QGIS Processing Script will not Validate

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am writing a script for QGIS that will identify the perimeter of only external facing walls.

The script is probably a little long to post directly into this post, but it is accessible [here](https://github.com/JamesMilnerUK/qgis-externalperimeter/blob/master/externalwalls.py).

The script works when I am in QGIS's script editor and hit run i.e. the dialog box comes up and all runs as expected.

[image]

However upon using the 'add script from file' button (Processing > Toolbox > Add script from file) I am greeted with the error:

```
The selected file does not contain a valid script
```

Unfortunately I can't seem to get any break down or tracestack of why this is the case. I've tried examining the [GitHub page for the function responsible](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/script/AddScriptFromFileAction.py) but am unable to uncover any answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
## Iterate through each of the buildings
```

That should be a single comment sign (#), not a double one, otherwise, it tries to parse it as if it was a parameter, and it fails

Yyou do not need to add the script from file. Just save it to the scripts folder, and it will be automatically added to the toolbox

Comment: This was the correct answer. The issue was having a double hash (##) as one of my normal comments. The double hashes are reserved for input variable assignment by QGIS Processing